# trying to install django and python using GIT-BASH on win7

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django for the first time and trying to work through http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-creating-a-dynamic-website/.

I have downloaded Django-1.4.3. here is my Git-Bash directory

```
$ ls
Django-1.4.3     ReleaseNotes.rtf  doc           git-cheetah  libexec
Git Bash.vbs     bin               etc           git-cmd.bat  share
README.portable  cmd               git-bash.bat  lib          ssl
```

according to the tutorial I have to execute:

```
cd Django-1.4.3
python setup.py install
```

when I do the latter I get:

```
$ python setup.py install
sh.exe": python: command not found
```

where do I need to put python to allow it to execute this command?

Comment: This is somewhat editorial, but if unless you're going to deploy to a windows server, i would highly, highly, highly encourage you to setup a local virtual linux machine with virtualbox/vagrant and do your django dev there.  A shared folder and a forwarded port is all it takes to make the virtual server feel like it is just another application running in windows.

Comment: I'm a newbie to this, so I appreciate your advice on this. I'm working mainly on a thumbdrive, in a windows environment. my experience up to now has been with php, so If you can recommend an article or link to get me started it would be much appreciated. regards, Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that Python is already installed, this error message means that Git-Bash doesn't know where your python.exe is.

To run the python command from the Git-Bash like you proposed, you have to append the path of python.exe in the `PATH` environment variable of Windows.

Other way to run python on Windows is using the normal command prompt (instead of Git-Bash) using the full path. For example, if the installation directory of python is `C:\Python27`:

```
cd Django-1.4.3
C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install
```